# Force on a dipole due to another dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, dipole-moment

The force on a dipole (with moment $\vec{p}_1$) in an electric field is given as $\vec{F} = (\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{E}$

Now lets say we have another dipole with moment $\vec{p}_2$ at the origin, exerting a force on the first dipole. Jackson (3rd edition), equation (4.13) has the electric field due to a dipole (at the origin) being

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\hat{n}(\vec{p}_2\cdot\hat{n}) - \vec{p}_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}|^3}$$

After substituting this into the force equation, we get

$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = (\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})\Bigg(\frac{\hat{n}(\vec{p}_2\cdot\hat{n}) - \vec{p}_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}|^3}\Bigg)$$

After which, I am a bit afraid to proceed. Now, the $(\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})$ term needs to be taken through the electric field term, although I am not sure how the gradient here interacts with everything inside the electric field term. I know $\hat{n}$ can be written as $\hat{n} = \vec{r}/|\vec{r}|$, so does the gradient affect $\hat{n}$? How do we deal with that fact that $|\vec{r}|^3$ is in an absolute value when we take the derivative? $\vec{p}_2$ should be unaffected because it doesn't depend on $\vec{r}$, right? Also, having $(\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})$ being a non-vector makes me nervous.

These sort of vector calculus calculations have always made me very uncomfortable. I need to iron this out. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, no reason to be nervous about $(\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})$; just like $\vec\nabla$, it is an operator. $(\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{A}$ is a directional derivative and can be thought of as the rate of change of $\vec{A}$ as you move along $\vec{p}_1$ (with "velocity" $\vec{p}_1$).

Using vector calculus identities can simplify such computations considerably. You will need the identities
$$ (\vec v\cdot\vec\nabla)(\phi\vec{A}) = (\vec v\cdot\vec\nabla\phi)\vec{A} + \phi(\vec v\cdot\vec\nabla)\vec{A} \tag{1}$$
$$ \vec\nabla f(\phi) = f'(\phi)\nabla\phi \tag{2}\ \ \ \text{(chain rule)} $$
$$ \vec\nabla(\vec A\cdot\vec B) = (\vec A\cdot\vec\nabla)\vec B + (\vec B\cdot\vec\nabla)\vec A + \vec A\times(\vec\nabla\times\vec B) + \vec B\times(\vec\nabla\times\vec A) \tag{3} $$
and the useful relation $\vec\nabla r=\hat{n}$ (prove this for yourself), where I have used the notation $r=|\vec r|$ for simplicity.

In particular, identity 2 is useful for gradients such as
$$\vec\nabla (r^m)=mr^{m-1}\vec\nabla r = mr^{m-1}\hat n  $$ Finally, to make your life easier, consider rewriting $\hat{n}$ as $\vec{r}/r$, since $\vec{r}$ is often easier to work with when derivative operators are involved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the final answer but I hope this helps with the vector multiplication.

First, expand everything (including $\nabla$) out into its unit vector components. I would use spherical coordinates so that $|\vec r|^3=r^3$ and $\hat n = <1, 0, 0>$, which should make life much easier, even though spherical $\nabla$ is a little more complicated than cartesian $\nabla$.

Use:

given:

$\vec a = <a_1, a_2, ..., a_n>$

$\vec b = <b_1, b_2, ..., b_n>$

Then:

$\vec a \cdot \vec b = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + ... + a_nb_n$

and:

$(\vec a \cdot \vec b)\vec c= a_1b_1\vec c + a_2b_2\vec c + ... + a_nb_n \vec c$

Note that unlike real vectors in the dot product, operators do **not** commute: you must retain the $\nabla$ operator and its unit vector components in the second multiplication position. $a_1\delta\vec c/\delta x$ does not necesarily equal $\delta(a_1\vec c)/\delta x$